# A set of measure zero in x-y plane

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

A set of measure zero in x-y plane has the property that almost every line parallel to the y-axis intersects it in a set of linear measure zero. What does this mean? How to write such statement in the form mathematical symbols ? And How to prove ?

Comment: It means precisely what you said. Nothing more and nothing less. If it meant something else, then it would have been stated differently. Would you mind clarifying what you actually mean to ask? What in the statement "A set of measure zero in x-y plane has the property that almost every line parallel to the y-axis intersects it in a set of measure zero" is not clear? (Regardless of whether you see a proof.)

Comment: Thank you. My question from a paper of  N.G. DE BRUIJN. "ON ALMOST ADDITIVE FUNCTIONS"

Comment: Do you know Fubini theorem? If you do, you can prove this theorem yourself. If you do not, you should pick a book on real analysis, including Lebesgue integral and read it.

Comment: Hi 

What means 'intersects it in a set of linear measure zero' ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about the set $\mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{Q}$ ? For any line $x\times\mathbb{R}$,
$$x\times\mathbb{R}\cap\mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{Q}=x\times\mathbb{Q}$$
if $x\in\mathbb{Q}$, which is countable; and the intersection is zero otherwise.

Comment: This is not a proof of the result. It is an example, and somewhat misleading, since measure $0$ sets can be much more complicated than countable sets. In your example, every section is of measure $0$ (in fact, countable), while in general, some sections do not need to be, which is why the statement mentions "almost all" rather than "all".